# Save socket with client identifier

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, serversocket

The problem: I have a Class that contains a Map< String, Socket >, which is static, and I use it as reference to get the Socket given the name of the client. But in order to do this, when the client is accepted by the server I should save his identifier, too. The problem is that his identifier is also the name of the client, and I don't know it until the client sends it and this happens only after the client is accepted.

My code:

Server Socket

```
public class SocketServer {
private int port;

private ServerSocket serverSocket;
private ExecutorService executorService;

public SocketServer(int port) {
    this.port = port;
    executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
}

public void startServer() {
    initServer();
    handleConnections();
    executorService.shutdown();
}

private void initServer() {
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // log exception
    }
}

private void handleConnections() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            executorService.submit(new ClientHandler(socket));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // log exception
            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Client Handler

```
public class ClientHandler implements Runnable {
private Socket socket;

public ClientHandler(Socket socket) {
    this.socket = socket;
}

public void run() {
    try {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Reader(socket));
        thread.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // log exception
    }
}

private void close() {
    try {
        objectOutputStream.close();
        socket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // log exception
    }
}
}
```

Reader

```
public class Reader implements Runnable {
private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Reader.class.getName());

private Socket socket;
private ObjectInputStream objectInputStream;


public Reader(Socket socket) throws IOException {
    this.socket = socket;
    objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            Visitable visitable = (Visitable)objectInputStream.readObject();
            Visitor visitor = new VisitorImpl();
            visitable.acceptVisitor(visitor);
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // log exception
        }
    }
}
}
```

In the while(true) i keep reading and I handle every kind of request through a Visitor Pattern. Here I have a Class implementing Visitable that can contain the Socket, so if I can set it the Visitor can register the client with his String and Socket, but in this part of the program I don't have access to the setters of the classes implementing the Visitable. I could do something like

```
if (visitable instanceof VisitableImplWithSocket) {
    ((VisitableImplWithSocket) visitable).setSocket(socket);
}
```

But I need this only one time (for every client) right after the client is accepted and it's inside a while loop, so I don't really like it. Any alternatives?

NOTE: I need the Class with the Map< String, Socket > because a client can decide how to connect to the server (socket or RMI) and I need to keep a reference to both the Socket and the Class on which I can do a RMI callback.
This class looks like

```
public class ListConnections {
    private static Map<String, Socket> CLIENT_SOCKET_MAP;
    private static Map<String, Registrable> CLIENT_RMI_MAP;
    ...
}
```

EDIT:

I need to keep a reference to the Client, in order to send a message to a specific Client at any given time. This reference should be the name of the Client, which is a String that is given as an input to the Client.

Client -> connect

Server -> accept client

Client -> send name

Server -> save Socket (or better, ObjectOutputStream) in a Map with the Client's name as the key.

And from now on the Server can send a message to the client whenever it needs.
It should be possible for more than one Client to connect at the same time (with uniques names).

As for now I did the following changes (seems to work, but I don't know if it's a good solution)

Client Handler (changes)

```
public void run() {
    try {
        objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Reader(socket, objectOutputStream));
        thread.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // log exception
    }
}
```

Reader (changes)

```
@Override
public void run() {
    SocketOutputMemory.add(Thread.currentThread().getId(), objectOutputStream);
    while (true) {
        try {
            Visitable visitable = (Visitable)objectInputStream.readObject();
            Visitor visitor = new VisitorImpl();
            visitable.acceptVisitor(visitor);
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // log exception
        }
    }
}
```

And right after the connection, when the Client sends its name, I do (in a VisitorImpl method that handles the responses)

```
ObjectOutputStream currentOutputStream = SocketOutputMemory.getOutputStream(Thread.currentThread().getId());
Connections.addClient(clientLogin.getClientName(), currentOutputStream);
```

And this is the new "memory" class that I use to associate the Thread ID with the ObjectOutputStream, so when the Client sends its name I can retrive the ObjectOutputStream.

```
public final class SocketOutputMemory {
private static Map<Long, ObjectOutputStream> objectOutputStreamMap;

private SocketOutputMemory()  {
    throw new IllegalAccessError("Utility class");
}

public static void init() {
    objectOutputStreamMap = new HashMap<>();
}

public static void add(Long threadId, ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream) {
    objectOutputStreamMap.put(threadId, objectOutputStream);
}

public static ObjectOutputStream getOutputStream(Long threadId) {
    return objectOutputStreamMap.get(threadId);
}
}
```

Comment: "*I use it as reference to **get the Socket given the name of the client***" - So the server assigns the client a name? "*But in order to do this, **when the client is accepted by the server I should save his identifier too***" - This doesn't make sense, could you elaborate? How does the identifier differ from the name? Why do you need both "***The problem is that the identifier is also the name of the client***" - If the identifier is the same as the name, why do you need both?

Comment: @VinceEmigh I tried to explain more. I actually found a solution, but I don't know if it's a good approach

Comment: Does the RMI and Socket connections abide by the same protocol? Or do they exist for different purposes? Your code is very static, which can cause design issues down the line. I can help you conjure up a flexible design, but you have to be more specific on how users will interact with server via RMI and Socket (does the client choose RMI OR Socket, or does the client use both side by side?) You can also [create a chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/new) if you'd like to go into detail about this

Comment: @VinceEmigh RMI and Socket abide by the same protocol, and the user choses RMI or Socket. A Client (= 1 user) can have only one connection alive to the server at the same time, but on a single computer I can have more than one client. We are talking about a card game (max 4 players), one player at a time sends his action to the server, which executes it and sends the response to all the others players in game. I could have different games alive at the same time (on the server I have a Game class that handles the players and their requests). Also I can't have more than one SocketServer. Thanks!